# How can I debug the browser in Captive Portal?

Tags: ios, iphone, debugging, captivenetwork

The Captive Portal has a browser that sometimes opens up when you attempt to connect to a wireless network.

Does anyone know how I can debug it?

What I've already tried:

1. I have tried running a simulator, but the simulator wont open the portal.
2. I have tried connecting an iPhone to my mac and debug using Safari - develop, but that only shows debug information when the iPhone is running Safari, not the Captive Portal.

Answer (score 2):

I've had to do this in the past, what worked for me was to grab the URL of the captive portal page (You can usually obtain this by using curl to visit google or something, and capturing the response which will redirect you to the captive portal page.)

Once you have the URL, just load it in mobile safari and use the debug mode. The captive portal window is just a `UIWebView` using mobile safari so the debug should be the same.

Unfortunately there's no way that I know to debug directly in the captive portal window.