# Running angularJS in an Captive Network Assistant (WISPr) on iOS and OSX

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, captivenetwork, wispr

From previous projects I know that Apple's Captive Network Assistant (aka WISPr client, too) runs a restricted browser, see [How can I debug the browser in Captive Portal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20652373/how-can-i-debug-the-browser-in-captive-portal) and [Ajax on Captive Network Assistant on iOS and OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20843992/ajax-on-captive-network-assistant-on-ios-and-osx).

My hotspot is running a angularJS web page. On a Windows Phone 8.1 and an OS X Lion my angular page works fine. On my iOS 8.3 there must be a JavaScript error somewhere in the code, because I can see the angular variable expressions `{{myVar}}` in the code which means the angular framework isn't loaded properly.

Any idea what could be the cause?

Comment: Does it work in Mobile Safari?

Comment: Yes, it does and it works pretty good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solved

Cause has been found, not by me but a friend of mine. Turns out that the CNA browser (WISPr client) doesn't allow the use of the browser's **local storage**. Whenever you try to write some data into the local storage, the application crashes.
Thus, the solution is either to switch from local storage to normal cookies or to do a user agent detection in JavaScript and exclude CNA browser (WISPr clients) from the use of the local storage.

Many thanks @chedabob, the idea of checking if JS is enabled led to the local storage check. Really appreciate your support.

Comment: Could you feature detect local storage in CNA, e.g. `typeof window.localStorage == 'undefined'`?

Comment: this is even a better approach!

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly use WeinRe to remotely debug it, however if the root of your problem is the Captive Portal view isn't running Javascript, this probably isn't going to help

https://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/

Comment: Thx @chedabob, I didn't know weinre yet. I experienced a bit with it because indeed it's seems to be a good approach. But unfortunately weinre requires the the debug_client and the debug_target to be able to communicate with each other in the network. On my WISPr-enabled router connected devices are not to see each other on the network. I can't turn the network separation off, so debugging using weinre doesn't seem to be an option for debuging a CNA browser (WISPr client).

Comment: back to the problem with the CNA browser (WISPr client). Javascript is enabled and working, just confirmed this by a "hello world" test script injected into the code.